# How to do logout with Meteor js to a user logged with facebook?

Tags: facebook, meteor

In my mobile app made with the meteor js, when the user login with facebook and try log out, when the user access the app again he has logged automatically. By the way, the user was not logged out.

This is my log out code:

```
Meteor.logout(function () {
  // redirect to login page
});
```

Comment: Not sure how this meteor stuff works, but I’m assuming it embeds the Facebook JS SDK to handle login client-side? It’s a _feature_ that a user that has logged in to your app before, is automatically recognized as logged in on their next visit to your site, if they are still logged in to Facebook at that time.

Comment: Can you please do the following to make this a bit easier to answer: Log out but don't login again or open the app or something. Open your mongo shell via `meteor mongo` and find the user, that has just logged out with `db.users.find(...)`. Copy the content of the user's file and add it to your post (please don't post it in the comments). Usually there should be still the access token from the oAuth handshake because, as @misorude assumed right, it is a feature.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the meteorlogintoken from local storage. You may also need to remove the resume token from a user in the users collection (if one exists).

Can’t say for sure as I don’t use Facebook with meteor but the above works for a standard meteor user

Answer (score 0):

To further help diagnose the problem, you can test if the call to `Meteor.logout` returned an Error in the callback, something like:

```
Meteor.logout(function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        // Re-direct to login page
    }
);
```

See: https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-logout